# clock_gettime is precision is only ms

Tags: c, arm, qnx, gettime

I'm running QNX on a microcontroller board with a 25MHz clock speed. Running `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);` gives me only a precision of ms. I'm aware that a precion of ns is not possible because of the low clock speed but us should be possible. Do I have to set some configuration flags to get a better precision?

Comment: AFAIK `clock_gettime` gives you us precision....

Comment: According to this its nano seconds: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref%2Ftopic%2Fc%2Fclock_gettime.html In my case the lower six decimal values are always zero.

Comment: Is 25MHz the system clock or the external crystal freq?

Comment: The System clock @LPs

Comment: And what hardware is `CLOCK_REALTIME` backed by on your platform? AFAICS it could be anything from a 25MHz cycle counter to some standard external 32KHz RTC chip.

Comment: Its a AM3354 microcontroller from Texas Instruments. The 25 MHz is from the SYSPAGE_ENTRY(qtime)->cycles_per_sec; I have to admit that I'm not familier with QNX and ARM so much.